# Django Query across multiple model relationships

Tags: django, django-models, filter, django-queryset, relationship

I'm trying to make a query for a set of instances in the ActivityPartsModel filtered by a group. When I try to run the following. I am left with an Attribute Error: "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'activity'"

```
activities = GroupActivityModel.objects.filter(group=id)
parts = ActivityPartModel.objects.filter(activity=activities.activity.all())
print(parts)
```

How would I go about filtering ActivityPartModel with a GroupModel ID/instance

```
class ActivityModel(models.Model):
    activityName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    workCenter = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

class ActivityPartModel(models.Model):
    activity = models.ForeignKey(ActivityModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    part = models.ForeignKey(PartModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    increment = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # TRUE/FALSE used to represent parts ActivityPartModel/produced
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=100_000)
    location = models.TextField(max_length=50, null=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

class GroupModel(models.Model):
    groupName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class GroupActivityModel(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(GroupModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(ActivityModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=100_000)
    groupName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
activities = GroupActivityModel.objects.filter(group=id).values_list('activity', flat=True)
parts = ActivityPartModel.objects.filter(activity__in=activities)
print(parts)
```

because activity is an attribute of model object and you can not call attribute of model object from queryset object (I mean the line `activity=activities.activity.all()`). That is why you're seeing `QuerySet' object has no attribute 'activity'"`.